# I am having trouble with creating a number range IF formula

Tags: reporting, formula, formula-field

I want My formula to show Tier 0 if lifetime account Revenue is between 0 and 999, Tier 1 if Lifetime Account revenue is between 1000 and 10000 and so on.

Here is the formula I have:

```
IF (Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 0, <= 999, "Tier 0",
IF (Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 1000, <= 10000, "Tier 1",
IF (Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 10001, <= 25000, "Tier 2",
IF (Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 25001, <=50000, "Tier 3",
IF (Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 50001, "Tier 4",
"")))))
```

I get a syntax error that says

> Error: Syntax error. Found '<='

Please Help!

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to put in two conditions in your IF statements, if you want to do that, then you need to use an `AND()` statement.  This should work for you

```
IF (AND(Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 0, Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <= 999), "Tier 0",
IF (AND(Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 1000, Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <= 10000), "Tier 1",
IF (AND(Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 10001, Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <= 25000), "Tier 2",
IF (AND(Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 25001, Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <= 50000), "Tier 3",
IF (Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 50001, "Tier 4",
"")))))
```

For more information on formulas and operators, take a look [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

There were some syntax errors with the formula (obviously). I find it easiest to format complex formulas like code, as it highlights missing statements etc. This should work:

```
IF (
    AND (
        Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 0, 
        Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <= 999
    ), 
    "Tier 0",
    IF (
        AND (
            Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 1000, 
            Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <= 10000 
        ),
        "Tier 1",
        IF (
            AND (
                Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 10001, 
                Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <= 25000
            ),
            "Tier 2",
            IF (
                AND (
                    Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 25001, 
                    Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c <=50000
                ), 
                "Tier 3",
                IF (
                    Lifetime_Account_Revenue__c >= 50001, 
                    "Tier 4",
                    ""
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```